# How should I filter items of a user?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, json-api

I am using Ember 1.13.2 and Ember Data 1.13.4. The API conforms to JSON API format (http://jsonapi.org/format).

A user has many items. Doing `{{model.items}}` in the template will return **ALL** items of the user.

What if I also need to display ONLY **blue** items from the user. How should I go about this?

```
// Route
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model(params) {
     // Executes: http://localhost:3099/api/v1/users/5
    return this.store.findRecord('user', params.user_id);
  }
})

// Template
firstName: {{model.firstName}} - works
<br>items: {{model.items}} - works
<br>blue items: {{model.items}} - what do we do about this?

// app/models/user.js
import DS from 'ember-data';
export default DS.Model.extend({
  items:        DS.hasMany('item', { async: true }),
  firstName:    DS.attr('string')
});

// app/models/item.js
import DS from 'ember-data';
export default DS.Model.extend({
  user:           DS.belongsTo('user', { async: true }),
  name:           DS.attr('string')
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I misunderstood the original question. It seems as if you want to *fetch* only the items where the color is blue (and avoid fetching the rest). For this, you'll need to query the server, which requires server-side code. But, once you have the server-side code done, you can do something like this:

```
blueItems: Ember.computed('items.@each.color', {
    get() {
        const query = {
            user: this.get('id'),
            color: 'blue'
        };

        return this.get('store').find('item', query);
    }
})
```

But again, you'll need your server to support querying for that data. (The JSON API states how you need to return the data, but you'll need to implement the query yourself.)

---

Old answer that filters the items after fetching for display (just for reference):

I would use a computed property:

```
blueItems: Ember.computed('items.@each.color', {
    get() {
        return this.get('items').filter((item) => {
            return item.get('color') === 'blue';
        });
    }
})
```

Or the shorthand ;)

```
blueItems: Ember.computed.filterBy('items', 'color', 'blue')
```

Not every operation has an Ember shorthand which is why I gave the full example first.

Using computed properties with promises is sometimes tricky, but this computed property should update whenever your `items` array updates.

Comment: Great answer, however this will need the API to fetch all items first before it can filter. Which might have an issue, if the user has several items. Or, is the API always expected to return a limit?

Comment: On a side-note. I don't think `sortBy` and `filter` (http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/06/18/ember-data-1-13-released.html#toc_ds-store-filter-moved-to-an-addon) exist in this version Ember 1.13.2

Comment: Ahh, I misunderstood. You don't want to _display_ only the blue items, you want to _fetch_ only the blue items. I'll update my answer. (Also, `sortBy` and `filter` still exist. The blog post you linked to is a different function. I also don't know why I wrote `sortBy` instead of `filter`. That's a typo.)

Comment: Am curious, what is the purpose of using `get()` inside the computed block? Is this alternative syntax for writing a computed property function?

Comment: It's the new way of writing a computed property, as detailed [here](http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/05/13/ember-1-12-released.html#toc_new-computed-syntax). The old way is actually deprecated (you should get warnings for it if you're on Ember 1.12+.)